# Google cache shows only header and footer. Skips body content

Tags: php, jquery, search-engine

I have an issue in my website. Looking up my site in search engines, and viewing the cached version of the index page, shows only the header and footer of the page. Everything in between is omitted. This issue is apparent only in the index page. Other pages on the site are fine.

[Here is the cached page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3asEcz9z-lhrsJ%3awww.mrkabat.com/%20&cd=12&hl=en&ct=clnk)

[Here's a direct link to the page.](http://www.mrkabat.com/)

**Things to note:**

- This issue does not seem to happen in Google search only, but also
  Bing and Yahoo.
- In Google cache, it's possible to display the text-only version of
  the page, which seems to SHOW the page just fine, including the omitted content but without style.
- In google webmaster tools, the page preview of the index page does
  not have this issue. It shows it just fine.
- The index page is using a jquery plugin to display the car brands,
  and it allows for sorting based on region/country. I don't know if
  this is the culprit.
- My site is in Arabic. Sorry if you don't understand anything .-.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google seems to have trouble parsing your document. You have 2 sets of `<html></html>` tags in your document, which could lead the Google engine to confusion and errors.

I would strongly recommend you to fix your HTML errors using W3 Validator, this will probably allow Google to parse your document without errors.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mrkabat.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks for the note. They were actually more than 3 tags, and doc types. My colleague was using a doc type for each included file in the php script to properly display the Arabic characters in Dreamweaver. I cleaned the code, and will fetch as google and see how it goes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will fix your issue. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: So.. apparently this did not fix the issue. Here's Bing's cache for 30th of July. [link](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=mrkabat&d=4617631677350844&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=4158b28,17ec26b7)

Comment: @Dullah Stange...  Have you tried using 'Fetch as Googlebot' option in Google Webmaster Tools? http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587

Comment: @Dullah I was not saying it is a Google specific problem. If there was an issue with crawlers in general you would see it with 'Fetch as Googlebot' tool. 'Fetch as Bingbot' would work too of of course.

Comment: There are no issues with either bots. I suppose it may be an issue with some javascripts?